# ERROR: When changing from one activity to the other

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-intent

When switching from one activity to the next activity, I get a selection of errors. The activity being switched to uses a custom listview, and I suspect an error here is causing all of my problems. I wonder whether passing an empty arraylist to my custom adapter causes this, because it reads from a file, which could cause it to return null.

This is my error (logcat from Eclipse):

```
01-02 06:13:26.239: E/File not found(1765): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 

/data/data/com.example.partyorganiser/files/PeopleDetailsFile: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.partyorganiser/com.example.partyorganiser.AddParty_PeopleList}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.example.partyorganiser.PeopleDetails[]
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.example.partyorganiser.PeopleDetails[]
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.example.partyorganiser.AddParty_PeopleList.onCreate(AddParty_PeopleList.java:37)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-02 06:13:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks for the help!! :)

EDIT: Code snippet:

```
package com.example.partyorganiser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AddParty_PeopleList extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView people_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.person_list_item);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_party__people_list);
        ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_list = Readpeopledetails();


        if(people_list != null){
            final peoplelist_customadapter adapter = new peoplelist_customadapter(this, R.layout.person_list_item,  people_list );
            people_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_party__people_list, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public ArrayList<PeopleDetails> Readpeopledetails(){
        String filereadfrom = "";///declares a string to read file contents into. then split into peopledetails.

        ///this was copied straight from AddPeople. Could place in another static class, and then access it from both, but this was a very quick
        ///quite untidy way of doing it.
        ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_array = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();


        try{
            InputStream filestream = openFileInput("PeopleDetailsFile");
            if (filestream != null){
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(filestream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);

                }
                filereadfrom = stringBuilder.toString();
                ///using two delimiters: ";" and ","
                ///split based on ";" to get people as a string, put in array

                String[] parsearray = filereadfrom.split(";");


                    for(String personstring: parsearray){
                        String[] split = personstring.split(",");


    PeopleDetails peopledetails_unit = new PeopleDetails("", "");

                        peopledetails_unit.name= split[0];
                        peopledetails_unit.number = split[1];
                        peopledetails_array.add(peopledetails_unit);


                }
                filestream.close();
                inputStreamReader.close();



                return peopledetails_array; }
        }





            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("File not found" , e.toString());
                return peopledetails_array;

                }

            catch(IOException e){
                Log.e("Can't read file" , e.toString());///this is useful 

    for debugging, to figure out the problem.

                return peopledetails_array;



            }
        return peopledetails_array;



    }

}
```

Comment: Show your code that will be easy to find error .

Comment: pls show your code there is casting problem

Comment: You are incorrectly casting an Object array to a PeopleDetails array. Can you post the related code from your 2nd activity? As an aside, an empty arraylist to an adapter is fine as long as that arraylist isn't null.

Comment: post your code to get some idea dude .

Comment: yeah, I think I've changed my current code so that the cast isn't faulty. Now it throws a different error.

Comment: Could you provide your code without modification and with logs?

Comment: log is at the top... or a different log?? i think where my code is going wrong is on this line - "ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_list = Readpeopledetails();" - another post of mine relating to the same method (reading method) points to this. What should this be, to get the return value of ReadpeopleDetails() into the arraylist people_list?? thanks!!

Comment: I don't see relation from logs to provided code. Your code throw java.lang.ClassCastException in line 37 but this line is related with menu. Are you sure that this current code?